# How to verify user through email during registration process

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, jwt, nodemailer

Hello guys am trying to implement user verification through email. The Link is sent to the email but when the link is clicked this is the response

This localhost page can’t be found No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:1001/activation/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJuYW1lIjoiUEFVTCBPVU1BIE9DSE9MTEEiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmNvY2hvbGxhcGF1bDAxQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImF2YXRhciI6eyJ1cmwiOiJodHRwOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjEwMDAvdXBsb2Fkcy9mYXZpY29uLTE2OTQ5MDM4OTA0MTMtOTc2MDU1NDM1LnBuZyJ9LCJwYXNzd29yZCI6ImpoYmpqampqampoYmoiLCJpYXQiOjE2OTQ5MDM4OTAsImV4cCI6MTY5NDkwNDE5MH0.UwrFTz4Yr-hGp7ddyIM-w85OI9BkVmT6eHQz5zzdAlk
HTTP ERROR 404

Front end running on port 1001 and backend port 1000

Here are my code snippets

user controller file

```
const express = require(`express`);
const router = express.Router();
const User = require(`../models/user`);
const ErrorHandler = require(`../utils/ErrorHandler`);
const { upload } = require(`../multer`);
const fs = require(`fs`);
const uuid = require("uuid");
const jwt = require(`jsonwebtoken`);
const sendMail = require(`../utils/sendMail`);
const catchAsyncErrors = require("../middlewares/catchAsyncErrors");
const sendToken = require("../utils/jwtToken");

router.post("/create-user", upload.single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;
  const userEmail = await User.findOne({ email });

  if (userEmail) {
    const filename = req.file.filename;
    const filepath = `uploads/${filename}`;

    fs.unlink(filepath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: `Error deleting file` });
      }
    });

    return next(new ErrorHandler(`User already exists`, 400));
  }

  const fileId = uuid.v4();
  const protocol = req.protocol;
  const host = req.get("host");
  const fileUrl = `${protocol}://${host}/uploads/${req.file.filename}`;

  const user = {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    avatar: fileUrl,
    password: password,
  };

  // Generate the activation token
  const activationToken = createActivationToken(user);

  // Construct the activation URL
  const activationUrl = `http://localhost:1001/activation/${activationToken}`;

  try {
    await sendMail({
      email: user.email,
      subject: "Activate Your Account",
      message: `Hello ${user.name}, please click on the link to activate your account: ${activationUrl}`,
    });
    res.status(201).json({
      success: true,
      message: `Please check your email: ${user.email} to activate your account`,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
  }
});



// Define a function to create an activation token
const createActivationToken = (user) => {
  return jwt.sign(user, process.env.ACTIVATION_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "5m",
  });
};

router.post(
  "/activation",
  catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const { activation_token } = req.body;

      // Verify the activation token
      const newUser = jwt.verify(
        activation_token,
        process.env.ACTIVATION_SECRET
      );

      if (!newUser) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("Invalid token", 400));
      }
      const { name, email, password, avatar } = newUser;

      let user = await User.findOne({ email });

      if (user) {
        return next(new ErrorHandler("User already exists", 400));
      }
      user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        avatar,
        password,
      });

      // Send the JWT token as a response
      sendToken(user, 201, res);
    } catch (error) {
      return next(new ErrorHandler(error.message, 500));
    }
  })
);

module.exports = router;
```

sendMail.js

```
const nodemailer = require(`nodemailer`);

const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: '../config/.env' });

const sendMail = async (options) => {
  
  const transpoter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.SMTP_HOST ,
    port: process.env.SMTP_PORT ,
    secure: true,
    service: process.env.SMTP_SERVICE ,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.SMTP_MAIL ,
      pass: process.env.SMTP_PASSWORD ,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: process.env.SMTP_MAIL ,
    to: options.email,
    subject: options.subject,
    text: options.message,
  };

  await transpoter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};

module.exports = sendMail;
```

JwtToken.js

```
// create token and saving that in cookies
const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  const token = user.getJwtToken();

  // Options for cookies
  const options = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    httpOnly: true,
  };

  res.status(statusCode).cookie(`token`, token, options).json({
    success: true,
    user,
    token,
  });
};

module.exports = sendToken;
```

here is my Frontend Route

```
<Route path='/activation/:activation_token' element={<ActivationPage />} />
```

ActivationPage.jsx

```
import  { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useSearchParams } from 'react-router-dom'
import { BASE_URL } from '../config';
import axios from 'axios';

const ActivationPage = () => {
    const { activation_token } = useSearchParams();
    const [error, setError] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (activation_token) {
            const activationEmail = async () => {
                try {
                    const res = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}/user/activation`, {
                        activation_token
                    });
                    console.log(res.data.message)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.response.data.message)
                    setError(true)
                }
            };
            activationEmail();
        }
    }, [activation_token])

    return (
        <div className='w-full h-screen flex justify-center items-center text-sm font-semibold'>
            {
                error ? (
                    <p>Your token is Expired!!</p>
                ) : (
                    <p>Your Account has been created successfully!!</p>
                )
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default ActivationPage;
```

i was expecting a page  with "Your Account has been created successfully!!"

Comment: Hey can you tell me your frontend & backend is running on which ports?

Comment: Front end running on port 1001 and backend port 1000

Answer (score 0):

Since your JWT contains hyphens or other special characters, React Router might not be handling it correctly. Try wrapping :activation_token with a regex to accept all characters. For example:

```
<Route path='/activation/:activation_token*' element={<ActivationPage />} />
```